# How to replace {!Custom_Object.Account.Name} in a string to real value?

Tags: apex, soql, string

We have a scenario to replace {!Custom_Object.Account.Name} to account name like that we have multiple value in that string.

```
String subject = 'Hello this account belongs to {!Custom_Object.Account.Name}';
String nameSub = subject.replace('{!Custom_Object.Account.Name}', acc.Name);
```

But in future the string may contains multiple values like Account phone, zip etc.. How to find all the field name inside {!XXX} and replace it.

Comment: Why not simply : `String subject = 'Hello this account belongs to ' + acc.Name;` ?

Comment: Basically the string was formed by third party app, for example consider the string - "Hello this account belongs to {!Custom_Object.Account.Name} and the Billing phone No : {!Custom_Object.Account.BillingPhone"; Here I need to find and replace the values included in {!xxx}.

Comment: I don't see where is the problem ! Why can't you do this :
`var name = ' {!Custom_Object.Account.Name}';
var phoneNumber = '{!Custom_Object.Account.BillingPhone};
var result = "Hello this account belongs to " + name  + " and the Billing phone No : " + phoneNumber`;

Comment: The string will be dynamic, we don't know whether it will include name or phone no. Consider the string included {!xxxx} we need to find xxxx and to replace it with real value.

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Generally, you should be able to demonstrate you have attempted to solve your own problem. Often times questions of this format will be closed. Instead of asking "How do I do X?", try to solve the problem and share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, are you just trying to preview an Email Template? I'm voting to close this question as unclear what you're asking until you come back and clarify. Please make sure to [edit] your question with any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play with the String methods here.

```
String subject = 'Hello this account belongs to {!Custom_Object.Account.Name}';
String dynPart = subject.subString(subject.indexOf('!')+1, subject.indexOf('}'));
dynPart= dynPart.subString(dynPart.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
System.debug(dynPart);
```

it will give you the field name, in this case `Name`.

now,

```
String nameSub = subject.replace(subject.subString(subject.indexOf('{')), acc.get(dynPart));
```

Comment: Please explain how a string will have a null pointer exception. The acc.get(dynPart) might return a null pointer exception if not found, but a string will be `isBlank()` or `isEmpty()`. Strings don't return null pointers.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I realize my mistake. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a good application for the use of RegEx. You'd want to have a positive lookbehind that looked like `(?<=^\saccount\sbelongs\sto\s$)`. You'll also need a positive lookahead which would be `($=^\sand$)`. What we need to find is the substring in between the two. If nothing follows the 1st string except a period, then there will need to be an optional find on the lookahead. I say this because we can look for a capture group that contains multiple words with the number of them being optional as the capture group in between. The group in between would be replaced with `'\{!Custom_Object.Account.Name\}'`.

For the next one, we'll need to find the substring that follows `(?<=^\sBilling phone No :\s$)`. What will be important here is the format it will appear in. That group could look like `(^\(\d\d\d\)\s\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\s$)` or `(^\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\s)` which could also be viewed as either `((\(0-9\)(\s)(-)(0-9)(-)(0-9)(\s?))` or `((0-9)(-)(0-9)-(0-9)(\s?))` Both of which get replaced with  `'\{!Custom_Object.Account.BillingPhone\}'`.

With any of these you'd want to be used with the `(/i)` universal ignore case modifier which is placed at the front of the capture groups.

To implement, you'd want to do something like this:

```
MyString = MyString.replaceFirst((/i)(?<=^\saccount\sbelongs\sto\s$)(\b\w)+($=^\sand$), `'\{!Custom_Object.Account.BillingPhone\}'`);
MyString = MyString.replaceFirst(`((\(0-9\)(\s)(-)(0-9)(-)(0-9)(\s?))|((0-9)(-)(0-9)-(0-9)(\s?)), '\{!Custom_Object.Account.BillingPhone\}');
```

Alternatively, you could use `split(RegEx)` which returns a list that contains each substring of the String that is terminated by either the regular expression regExp or the end of the String. In that manner, if you had a match for any of the RegEx's you're looking for, if a match was found in any of the strings returned, you could do the replacement and easily reassemble the complete string. That would be what I'd recommend once you begin looking for zip codes and other fields.

Comment: I think the OP was going for something more generic here?

Comment: @AdrianLarson A generic solution would be fairly simple for replacing telephone numbers and zip codes, but account names aren't formatted nearly so clearly as to be able to determine that's what they are. `Split()` would provide the most generic solution along with a RegEx that covered all the possibilities. I'm not certain the OP phrased his question sufficient to  elicit a more generic solution considering that this answer was based on his comments.

Comment: I think he just wants to replace a merge expression with the corresponding record data, but I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I didn't get that at all from the text of the question, but I can see where you could get that from the title of it. It's genuinely unclear to me now that you've brought that to my attention. I don't know where the data would come from if it wasn't merged data. That makes the question quite unclear.

Comment: Well that we can both agree on!